# Validation Rule To Allow Only One Checked Record

Tags: apex, validation

I have a custom object `Object_X`, which has a checkBox field `Activate__c`. My requirement is that only one `Object_X` type record can have the `Activate__c` checked at any given time. So if `Object_X` already has a record with `Activate__c` checked, another record with `Activate__c` checked should not be allowed to be created.

I already have a trigger for this but I'm wondering if there is a way this can be easily achieved by a validation rule.

Comment: who can edit the activate flag, and how many times do you think the activate flag on the record needs to be changed?

Comment: Anyone who has access to the Object_x can edit the Activate flag. There is no limit of number of times the flag can change, only that if the flag of one record changes I need to check all other Object_X records in the table to see if there is another record before allowing to save it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: Trigger may be the best route for the given situation.

AFAIK You cannot iterate over a set of  records using validation rule.Can the activate flag be edited by anyone in the system? If so I would stick to trigger approach, else I can think of a crazy solution which might be an alternative to code approach but more maintenance for the admin every time the flag is changed on the object X.

Step1: Create a custom label which holds the Id of the opportunity where activate = true.

Step2 : Create a validation rule to check both new opptys and updates to existing oppty.

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISNEW(),
        Activate__c = true
    ), 
    AND( 
        Id != $Label.custom_label_name,
        ISCHANGED(Activate__c ),
        Activate__c = true 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 5):

One other validation rule approach would work if the Object_x is a detail in a master detail relationship. You could count the number of detail records that have the Activate__c = true. Then create a validation rule to fire when the count is greater than one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure only one active record in your entire org, I would use a trigger that uses a service class like below:

```
public without sharing class ObjectServices
{ // This should be enforced even if someone doesn't have the right visibility
    public static Boolean hasActiveObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (hasActiveObject == null)
            {
                hasActiveObject = [
                    SELECT count() FROM Object_X__c WHERE Activate__c = true
                ] > 0;
            }
            return hasActiveObject;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public static void validateActiveObjects(List<Object_X__c> records)
    {
        if (!hasActiveObject) return;
        for (Object_X__c record : records)
        {
            if (record.Activate__c)
                record.addError(Label.Only_One_Active_Object);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this

```
    List<Object__x> objList = [SELECT ID,Activate__c WHERE Activate__c = true];
if(objList.size()>0){
   here you can insert new record in Object__x
}
```