# Trigger to allow only one checked record or to update other records

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

Hard to describe what I need in a title.

I am not a developer, but it seems I can't do this with a validation rule. And since this is a managed package field, I have no direct access to change the field properties

We have an object called `Payment Method` where you can add in multiple payment methods. There is a checkbox field called `Default` where you can specify more than one default payment method. I'm looking for a way to have only one default payment method selected. Ideally, if a new payment method is created, I'd like to update any other payment methods to remove the default payment if the checkbox is selected.

I saw a post similar to mine here (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/80599/15132) and was wondering if this is the route I need to go.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not a developer, you can actually build this in a flow. It should only take a few minutes to build.

Create a Record-Triggered Flow that fires on insert and update for the Payment Method. First, check if the record is set to default, and if so, go to the next step, otherwise end. Next, get all of the payment methods that are also default for the specified record, something like "`Contact__c` Equals `{!$Record.Contact__c}` and Id Does Not Equal `{!$Record.Id}`". After that, loop through each payment method that was retrieved and uncheck the boxes. Finally, you'll save your record.

Remember to save and activate this flow when you're done.

The entire flow looks like this:

[image: Uncheck other Default Payment Methods]

---

If you really want a validation rule, that's only possible if there is a master-detail relationship on the object. You can create a Rollup Summary Field, count the number of default-checked records, and then use a validation rule to prevent multiple records from being default:

```
Count_of_Default_Payments__c > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an example. This did the trick with a flow.